# How to nest more IF conditions in excel when first condition becomes FALSE?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

The excel not accepting the formula

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!BZ2<>"",Sheet1!CB2<>"",Sheet1!CD2<>"",Sheet1!CF2<>"",Sheet1!CH2<>"",Sheet1!CA2="",Sheet1!BC2="B"), IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1),
    IF(
        IF(AND(Sheet1!BZ2<>"",Sheet1!CA2="",Sheet1!BC2="A"),IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1),
            IF(
                IF(AND(OR(Sheet1!DB2="Completed - Knowledge Transfer"),AND(Sheet1!BC2<>"")),IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1),
                IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",Sheet1!CA2)
                  )
       )
  )
```

I am following the below syntax for `IF` .

`=IF (logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])`

I am trying to nest the other conditions whenever the statements gets `FALSE`
Please help.

Can someone pls find the syntax error I am doing in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The If statement isn't nested properly and also you are using some AND Or statements which are again not used properly.

Simplifying your formula we get this

```
=IF(a,b,IF(IF(c,d,IF(IF(e,f,g)))
```

where ,

```
 a = AND(Sheet1!BZ2<>"",Sheet1!CB2<>"",Sheet1!CD2<>"",Sheet1!CF2<>"",Sheet1!CH2<>"",Sheet1!CA2="",Sheet1!BC2="B") 

 b = IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1)

 c = AND(Sheet1!BZ2<>"",Sheet1!CA2="",Sheet1!BC2="A")

 d = IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1)

 e = AND(OR(Sheet1!DB2="Completed - Knowledge Transfer"),AND(Sheet1!BC2<>""))This does not make sense

 f = IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1)

 g = IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",Sheet1!CA2)
```

A proper nested IF will be of the form

```
=IF(a,b,IF(c,d,IF(e,f,g)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your formula can also be written as:

```
=IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",
IF(OR(
AND(Sheet1!BZ2<>"",Sheet1!CB2<>"",Sheet1!CD2<>"",Sheet1!CF2<>"",Sheet1!CH2<>"",Sheet1!BC2="B"),
AND(Sheet1!BZ2<>"",Sheet1!BC2="A"),
AND(Sheet1!DB2="Completed - Knowledge Transfer",Sheet1!BC2<>"")),
TODAY()-1,Sheet1!CA2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax is a nested syntax (assuming a1 = 12 and b2=15:)

```
=IF(A1<13,IF(B1>13,"B1","Not Found"),"Not Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You overused `IF()` formula. I tried to simplify your formula, check this:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!BZ2<>"",Sheet1!CB2<>"",Sheet1!CD2<>"",Sheet1!CF2<>"",Sheet1!CH2<>"",Sheet1!CA2="",Sheet1!BC2="B"),IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1),IF(AND(Sheet1!BZ2<>"",Sheet1!CA2="",Sheet1!BC2="A"),IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1),IF(OR(Sheet1!DB2="Completed - Knowledge Transfer",Sheet1!BC2<>""),IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1),IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1))))
```

Nested view of formula above:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!BZ2<>"",Sheet1!CB2<>"",Sheet1!CD2<>"",Sheet1!CF2<>"",Sheet1!CH2<>"",Sheet1!CA2="",Sheet1!BC2="B"), 
    IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1),IF(AND(Sheet1!BZ2<>"",Sheet1!CA2="",Sheet1!BC2="A"),
        IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1),
        IF(OR(Sheet1!DB2="Completed - Knowledge Transfer",Sheet1!BC2<>""),    
              IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1),
              IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",TODAY()-1)
        )
     )
  )
```

Comment: Your formula got accepted but its does not seems a nested formula .Its overwriting and converting all values to todays date . The False statment condition in your formula isnot nested .

Comment: You should explain your criteria.

Comment: Use IF formula like this: `IF('criteria',TRUE,IF('criteria',TRUE,IF('criteria',TRUE,IF('criteria',TRUE,IF('criteria',TRUE,IF('criteria',TRUE,IF('criteria',TRUE,FALSE)))))))`