# How to highlight the cell by conditional formatting by comparing two columns ignoring BLANK match?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to highlight the cell by conditional formatting by comparing two columns B and C

The condition is like to ignore BLANKS even if both columns have blanks on same row ,only to highlight the matching values
So I wrote

`=AND(B2=C2,C2<>"")`

Please note the empy cells are not empty . If we click on empty cell , there's a hidden `IF` formula .But the value of cell is blank.

Its not working . Pls help

Comment: Works for me, what exactly is the issue? Are you getting some conditional formats displaying where you don't expect them? None displaying at all? Please explain the issue a bit more and I should be able to help... Thank you.

Comment: There are so many potential causes, a more detailed explanation of what you are experiencing will help me diagnose the cause and be able to offer the solution, please consider what I have mentioned in the above comment and explain the output you get when using the conditional format formula.

Comment: Compare your formatting rule with my flie: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1akxqYlhRbmpoX0U

Comment: Can I have the `IF` formula that's in column C please? Might be able to tweak a workaround and I will have the correct formula to play with on my sheet. Thanks.

Comment: @bzimor Logically your sheet is correct and works good in your case but the same formula is not working in my datasheet. I guess for blank `""` we need to give some other syntax and the cell value is blank but has `IF` formula when we click on that cell . May be because of that its not reading the formula

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor The formula is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739779/how-to-nest-more-if-conditions-in-excel-when-first-condition-becomes-false . The cell values I am getting in my columns are the result of this formula. Some cells are blanks but you will see this formula if you click on those blank cell.

Comment: Damn was hoping to track the FALSE from the IF but it's nested and could produce "" in more than 1 way

Comment: Try: `=AND(B2=C2,LEN(C2)<>0)` to check that the length of the cell value is 0 instead

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor Not working buddy. DAMNI am pissed off this column now !!!!.GRRR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

```
=AND($B2<>"",$C2<>"",$B2=$C2)
```

Follow the steps in the below GIF to see how to use it - [Conditional Formatting GIF](http://gph.is/2gB0nSn)

### The logic

Fixate **only the columns** B and C, and make sure that you apply the rule on the first cells of the selected range, in this case it's row number 2.
Excel will look interpret the formula this way -

1. Condition - Apply the fill in color only if all of the rules apply in the AND function
2. $B2<>"" - checking that the first cell in the selected range is not blank.
3. $C2<>"" - checking that the first cell in the selected range is not blank.
4. $B2=$C2 - checking that the first two cells in the selected range are equal.
5. Apply the same rule for the rest of the selected range according to given fixation - columns B and C.

According to 5 - Excel loops over your selected range like this -

```
=AND($B3<>"",$C3<>"",$B3=$C3)
=AND($B4<>"",$C4<>"",$B4=$C4)
...
=AND($B9<>"",$C9<>"",$B9=$C9)
```

That's an awesome magic trick in Excel's conditional formatting.

For practice purposes, I suggest you try highlighting the whole line according to the same condition.
And I also suggest you try to fixate $B$2 and $C$2 - Excel will interpret your formula only on these cells because you fixated it on them, that's a common mistake so watch out.

I hope it helps

Comment: @user41048 Glad to see it was solved, it was just the vertical focus then. I thought about it but disregarded it as the original formula didn't contain it and CF defaults with it... Meh.

Comment: That's a very common issue, I usually teach it this trick when I teach about conditional formatting :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in conditional formatting rule:

```
=IF(AND(B2=C2,C2<>""),TRUE)
```

Comment: The `And()` formula returns true/false by default though, is there a version difference with it or something?

Comment: There is no difference though, just as an option

Comment: Its not working !! If I simply gives `=C2` , All the matching cells highlights including blanks too.But I want to ignore blanks. Your formula is not working

Comment: Download my example file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1akxqYlhRbmpoX0U

Comment: Double check your existing rules, be sure that one of your old rules isn't conflicting and that the new rule hasn't been forced as a string (had `""` put around everything)

Comment: I mean to say if you empty your `row9 `ie; `value6`in your sheet you shared then the cell `B8` will also highlight since BLANK BLANK in both. I want to ignore that BLANK match

Comment: Did you check my file?

Comment: Are your blank values truly blank, as in could they be spaces?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor its empty not purely blank. If you click on empty cell you will see `IF` formula. But the cell is empty.

Comment: I tried it with `IF` based blank, it works perfectly

Comment: Same, I can't work out the issue here, are you sure you have set the different format (silly question but worth the ask) try using a nested if and if that doesn't work I might need some example data `=IF(C2="",FALSE,IF(B2=C2,TRUE))`