# Excel Macro to validate 2 columns based on cell values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am at initial stage in creating Macros. I know how to validate one column at a time, but not sure about validating a column reference to other column in the same row. Hope someone will help me with this!

Scenario: validate 2 columns in a spreadsheet (debit and credit columns).

Condition: For every filled row, I should have one of the two column values as "0",
highlight both the columns if non of the column value is "0".

[image: Attached is the sample data]

Comment: Is it mandatory to use macros? Have you tried conditional formatting?

Comment: Check my solution, it might solve your query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765719/how-to-highlight-the-cell-by-conditional-formatting-by-comparing-two-columns-ign/40767157#40767157

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use VBA, use the built-in Conditional Formatting.

Assuming those columns are A and B, let's say `A2:A10` and the Credit is `B2:B10`.

Go to Conditional Formatting, New Rule.

Select "Use a formula to determine ..." and type in `=AND($A2<>0,$B2<>0,$A2<>"",$B2<>"")`. Then click "Format" and Fill Red.

Then click "Ok", "Ok" and change "Applies to" range to `$A$2:$B$10`.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response. Actually I want to highlight the column if both the columns are zero also . but I think I  can do that by adding a condition Via VBA. Thank you so much for your time . :)

Comment: @Sai - Try `=OR(AND($A2<>0,$B2<>0,$A2<>"",$B2<>""),AND($A2=0,$B2=0,$A2<>"",$B2<>""))`